# Write embedded lists in a list as lines in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list with sublists each time consisting of a string, another string and then a list consisting of strings like this:

```
big_list = [['sentence', 'translation', ['error1', 'error2','error3']], ['sentence','translation',['error1','error2']],['sentence','translation',['error1', 'error2','error3','error4']]]
```

and I want to print each embedded list on a separate line with the elements in the list separated by a tab and the elements in the embedded list  with a comma
like this:

```
sentence   translation   error1, error2, error3
sentence   translation   error1, error2
sentence   translation   error1, error2, error3, error4
```

if all elements within the sublists would be strings the following code works fine.

```
with open (outputfile, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in big_list)
```

But with the third element in the sublist being a list, it becomes more complicated and I don't know what the best way is to tackle this issue?

All that I can think of is converting the embedded list in the sublist first to a string also with the `"".join(j) + "," for j in subsublist`,

So I tried the following:

```
string_errors = ("".join(j) + "," for j in dict["trg_errors"])
```

But it says the type is a generator object and not a string.
So then I am still not able to use my `writelines`function.
How can I make it a string?
And are there more efficient ways to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert to a reasonable data structure before trying to write out. A normal structure for sets of data like this would be a tuple of strings, so let's think about how you'd get that:

```
# pseudo-code:
[(sentence, translation, comma-separated_errors) for ? in big_list]
```

That'll get us the structure we're looking for, but how do we get to that `comma-separated_errors` from the list of errors we'll start with, and what is the `?` we're iterating over? Let's look at those one at a time.

Your list of errors is a list of strings, and iterators of strings have the handy `str.join` method to glue them all together, so `", ".join(error_list)` will get us that.

`big_list` is a list of lists, where each inner list is `[sentence, translation, error_list]`. That's easy to pull out with list unpacking.

Put it all together and we have:

```
lines = [(sentence, translation, ', '.join(error_list)) for sentence, translation, error_list in big_list]
```

---

Once we have the right data structure, it's as easy as calling `'\t'.join(line) for line in lines` in `writelines`.

```
with open("outputfile.tsv", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines("\t".join(line) for line in lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling the tab join, you can build a new list of strings and then call it (you were thinking in the right direction):

```
for l in big_list:
    print('\t'.join(l[0:-1] + [', '.join(l[-1])]))
```

This part `', '.join(l[-1])` converts the sublist in `l` into a string separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do

```
def get_rows(big_list):
    for small_list in big_list:
        colums = []
        for item in small_list:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                colums.append(item)
            elif isinstance(item, list):
                colums.append(', '.join(item))
        yield '\t'.join(colums)

with open ('tmp_big', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(get_rows(big_list)))
```

or

```
def get_words(big_list):
    for small_list in big_list:
        for item in small_list:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                yield item + '\t'
            elif isinstance(item, list):
                yield ', '.join(item) + '\n'

 with open ('tmp_big', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(''.join(get_words(big_list)))
```

making get_rows as generator will save us space as big list is expected to be big.